# Certificate replacement

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a specific method or process to replace all of the certificates required in a Kubernetes 1.7 cluster? Is this even possible?

Client is worried about using certificate auth and not being able to revoke/blacklist certs properly if someone leaves.

Comment: The [docker-kubernetes-tls-guide](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/docker-kubernetes-tls-guide) might help in finding the correct paths